# Why do I have this wrong output using Arduino Keyboard?

Tags: arduino, keyboard, keyboard-events

So I am programming a Rubber Ducky using an Atmega32U4 microcontroller, I have written a simple Arduino script that takes the keyboard an enters twich.tv when connected.

```
#include "Keyboard.h"

 void typeKey(uint8_t key)
 {
Keyboard.press(key);
delay(50);
Keyboard.release(key);
 }

 /* Init function */
 void setup()
{
// Begining the Keyboard stream
Keyboard.begin();

// Wait 500ms
delay(500);

 Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
 Keyboard.press('r');
 Keyboard.releaseAll();

 delay(500);
 Keyboard.print("chrome.exe");

 typeKey(KEY_RETURN);

 delay(1000);
 Keyboard.print("https://www.twitch.tv/");
 typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
 // Ending stream
 Keyboard.end();
 }

 /* Unused endless loop */
 void loop() {}
```

When I connect the USB and the program starts I get this output in the browser: httpsÑ--www.twitch.tv-

I don't really know if it is for my laptop or what, I am using an spanish keyboard, this is my Keyboard:
[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? help is much appreciated

Comment: what happens if you switch the keyboard layout to US for example?

Comment: @Piglet thanks, changing the keyboard language solved it!